# Android: Unable to start activity

Tags: android, eclipse, android-asynctask

Although, i used **AsyncTask** to make a new thread for calling the data from the server, still the app crashes when i move to this activity. I can not specify the cause of the error. Any help??????

```
public class CustomizedListView extends Activity {
static final String URL = "http://www.Vatrina-eg.com/men_tops.xml";
static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";
ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... strings) {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
        // looping through all song nodes <song>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
            map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsList.add(map);
            // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
            adapter=new LazyAdapter(CustomizedListView.this, songsList);        
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        return songsList;
    }
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainlistview);
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_listview);
    new DownloadFilesTask().execute(URL);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
        }
    });     
}   
}
```

LogCat:

```
09-12 22:12:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(19571): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
09-12 22:12:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(19571): Process: com.vatrina.eg, PID: 19571
09-12 22:12:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(19571): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-12 22:12:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(19571):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
09-12 22:12:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(19571):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
09-12 22:12:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(19571):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
09-12 22:12:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(19571):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
09-12 22:12:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(19571):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
09-12 22:12:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(19571):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
09-12 22:12:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(19571):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
09-12 22:12:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(19571):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
09-12 22:12:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(19571): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
09-12 22:12:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(19571):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6915)
09-12 22:12:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(19571):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.focusableViewAvailable(ViewRootImpl.java:3227)
09-12 22:12:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(19571):    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:660)
09-12 22:12:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(19571):    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:660)
09-12 22:12:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(19571):    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:660)
09-12 22:12:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(19571):    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:660)
09-12 22:12:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(19571):    at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:9642)
09-12 22:12:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(19571):    at android.view.View.setFocusableInTouchMode(View.java:6343)
09-12 22:12:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(19571):    at android.widget.AdapterView.checkFocus(AdapterView.java:777)
09-12 22:12:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(19571):    at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:487)
09-12 22:12:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(19571):    at com.vatrina.eg.CustomizedListView$DownloadFilesTask.doInBackground(CustomizedListView.java:59)
09-12 22:12:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(19571):    at com.vatrina.eg.CustomizedListView$DownloadFilesTask.doInBackground(CustomizedListView.java:1)
09-12 22:12:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(19571):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
09-12 22:12:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(19571):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
09-12 22:12:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(19571):    ... 4 more
```

Comment: You never initialize `list`.

Comment: I initialized it, but no change.
`ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_listview);`

Comment: Change that to `list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_listview);`. Adding the `ListView` in front makes it a local variable.

Comment: Done. Then, how to initialize list?

Comment: See my answer below. Remove the initialization you added since it's not in the right method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `onCreate` to this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainlistview);
    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_listview);
    new DownloadFilesTask().execute(URL);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
        }
    });     
}
```

Comment: Done. But still crashes.
`09-12 22:04:26.263: E/AndroidRuntime(17627): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
09-12 22:04:26.263: E/AndroidRuntime(17627): Process: com.vatrina.eg, PID: 17627
09-12 22:04:26.263: E/AndroidRuntime(17627): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-12 22:04:26.263: E/AndroidRuntime(17627):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
09-12 22:04:26.263: E/AndroidRuntime(17627):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)`

Comment: Is there anything else in that log?

Comment: Edit your question with the new logcat error. The important part comes after the part you pasted here. Also, you should move the assigning the list adapter to the onPostExecute method. It should only be done once, rather than each iteration of that loop.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `list` is still NULL when you attempt to access it in `onCreate()`.